# Manual check an checkbox and using jquery fire trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, checkbox, checked

I have some code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#a").click(function(){
        $("#b").trigger("click");
    });

    $("#b").click(function(){
        alert($("#b").prop("checked"));
    });
});
```

And here is HTML code:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a"></input>
    <input type="checkbox" id="b"></input>
</form>
```

In case, manual click the 'b' check box, it will show up 'true' but if checked 'a' it will show 'false' then change prop checked of b to true.

Can anyone show me how to get current prop checked of b please. I must fire event check b from a and itself, but when do that, i can't check whether that b is checked or not

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#a").click(function() {
        $("#b").prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

Comment: :-? then checkbox b will fire click event itself ? what I need here is b must fire jQuery click event handle when i click on a or itself, and on b event handle it must be new value of checked prop

Answer (score 0):

Just use setTimeout. It give b enough time to check before showing an alert:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#a").click(function(){
                $("#b").click();
            });

            $("#b").click(function(){
                setTimeout('alert($("#b").prop("checked"));',0);
            });
        });
```

Comment: nice idea, but it seem could not use in my case, this is alot of code action inside event handle base on b element, i wonder how to detach it to specify function, but when i try i cant call that detach function.... what about, how to get updated value before execute any action :-?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, It's easy than I thought. Just change the Click event to Change event, Click fire before the Change do, so on Change event I can get new value and can't on Click event

Comment: hmm, don't know why but when change to use Change event handle, I must trigger to fire Click event, instead of Change to have right state of checkbox